# Can't access location after app is killed

Tags: android, location, android-workmanager, locationmanager, foreground-service

I'm working on android app that should collect user geolocation (if the user agrees ofc ) every 15 minutes. I'm familiar with concept of WorkManger and I'm using it for executing PeriodicWork. Also, main reason I'm using it is that it works after device reboot.

I'm using LocationManager instead of Fused because one of my requirements is possible distribution outside of Play Store.

The problem is: when app is killed (recent items -> swipe) worker still executes LocationWork, but provider returns always null. I've heard about background location limitations so I've tried to move this functionality to foreground service. Unfortunately, it didn't change anything.

My code:

```kotlin
class GeoLocationWorker(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParameters) {

    private var requestQueue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)

    override fun doWork(): Result {

        Log.i("GLW", "before sleep")
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        Log.i("GLW", "after sleep")
        Log.i("GLW", "location lookup start")

        applicationContext.startForegroundService(Intent(applicationContext, GeoService::class.java))
        return Result.success()

    }
}
```

```kotlin
class GeoService : Service() {
    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        stopForeground(true)
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        startForeground()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun startForeground() {
        val channelId =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                createNotificationChannel("my_service", "My Background Service")
            } else {
                ""
            }

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        val notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build()
        startForeground(101, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)
        val locationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        /* no checking for permissions, because this code is executed only after successful request
            for ACCESS_LOCATION_*
         */

        locationManager.getCurrentLocation(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            null,
            applicationContext.mainExecutor,
            {
                if (it == null) {
                    Log.e("location", "location == null")
                } else {
                    Log.i("location", it.toString())
                }
                stopForeground(true)
            })
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel(channelId: String, channelName: String): String {
        val chan = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
        )
        chan.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        val service = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        service.createNotificationChannel(chan)
        return channelId
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```xml
 <service
            android:name="a.b.c.d.GeoService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location" />
```

Requesting permissions:

```kotlin
class PermissionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_permission)
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    fun askForPermissions(view: View) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ),
            1
        )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        for (i in permissions.indices) {
            if (permissions[i] == android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {

                val request =
                    PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<GeoLocationWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .build()

                WorkManager
                    .getInstance(this)
                    .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                        WorkerConfig.LOCATION_WORKER,
                        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                        request
                    )
            }
        }
        finish()
        startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you allowed the background location permission?

Comment: @Nitish yes, I have it in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Can you add the code where you have requested the location from user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution. Nitish's comments helped me a lot but main problem was something I missed in documentation:

> Caution: If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, the system enforces this best practice. If you request a foreground location permission and the background location permission at the same time, the system ignores the request and doesn't grant your app either permission.

Working permission request code:

```kotlin
class PermissionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_permission)
    }

    fun askForPermissions(view: View) {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ),
                1
            )

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == 1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                ),
                2
            )
            return
        }

        for (i in permissions.indices) {
            if (permissions[i] == android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {

                val request =
                    PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<GeoLocationWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .build()

                WorkManager
                    .getInstance(this)
                    .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                        WorkerConfig.LOCATION_WORKER,
                        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                        request
                    )
            }
        }
        finish()
        startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been working with a library that follows best practices for different versions, please have a look if it can be useful. All feedback is welcome! https://github.com/warting/permissions-ui

Answer (score 0):

From android 10 and above , you need to request `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` to get the location while app is in background - [Request Location Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Update your location code:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
             // requesting background location
       BottomNavigationActivity.this.requestPermissions(
          new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                      MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION);

  } else {
       MyActivity.this.requestPermissions(
          new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                     MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
  }
```

Comment: I've tried this before but adding this permission to request causes dialog to not even show up and results in -1 value for every grantResult

Comment: @jjakubowski Can you update your code requesting the permission ,so that we can look for the error

Comment: I've figured it out and posted an answer. Thank you for your help - it directed me to the solution